Should I remove laminate flooring before installing Ikea Sektion cabinets?
I'm looking to do the classic Ikea Section + Billy built in cabinet look in our breakfast nook. I have - generally - a pretty good sense of what I need to based on research and limited home improvement experience. The one main question I've been unable to answer is what to do about our flooring.
We have ~15 year old laminate wood flooring, possibly glued down (this is based on adjacent units in our townhouse complex, but not a sure thing). We will likely be redoing all our flooring, but not for another 3 to 5 years at least. The flooring runs parallel to the cabinets we'll be installing.
Trying to make a contractor's/my life easier and avoid removing the built-ins when we do redo the floors; would it be best to cut and remove the existing flooring under the cabinets now and leave the exposed concrete slab from the toe kick back, leave everything as is and just live with the orphaned board underneath the cabinets in the future, or is there a third better option I'm missing?

Since the new (future) flooring may not be the same thickness as the current floor, It would make sense to remove the flooring that would would be under the built in.
This removes the possibility of issues because of differences in the flooring.

The sektion legs can be removed easily and the flooring pulled later. I would personally remove it now but if its glued down you can likely save yourself some trouble now and leave it. In the futured if the contractor needs to remove a row or two they can pull the front legs and pry up the flooring adjacent to the toe kicks.
